# what is the de facto build command for a -dev package?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake, build

I'm working with https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev

Found there's *-dev lib under ubnutu apt-get

```
libshadowsocks-libev-dev - lightweight and secure socks5 proxy (development files)
```

But with the default make, it didn't generate the so as I expected, Just excuted binaries

Also I've tried with some grep search under the source code still cant figure it out

So Could any told me how to build the libshadowsocks-libev-dev, more specificly the libshadowsocks-libev.so

Beyond that, for all those *-dev package, is there any formal build steps?

Comment: "But with the default make, it didn't generate the so as I expected, Just excuted binaries" - The project actually creates shared (`.so`) library. This is performed by that line in [src/CMakeLists.txt]: `add_library(shadowsocks-libev-shared SHARED ${LIBSHADOWSOCKS_LIBEV_SOURCE})`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thx! I was knowing few about CMake, so I missed it. Finally, I’ve found out it controlled by a flag. After manually change then it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not like there is any very specific guidance for `-dev` packages in general. The person who created the package created a `debian/rules` and its supporting infrastructure which builds two or more packages from the upstream package source, and decided to put some of those files in the `-dev` package so that people who only need the binary can install only the binary, and people who want more can install both packages.

Typically, the non`-dev` package installs the library file, and the `-dev` package contains C header files and/or similar resources for someone who wants to compile code which uses this library.

The Github project for this package contains the definitions in https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/tree/master/debian -- in particular, [`libshadowsocks-libev-dev.install`](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/blob/master/debian/libshadowsocks-libev-dev.install) installs the `.so` (probably a symlink) while [`libshadowsocks-libev2.install`](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/blob/master/debian/libshadowsocks-libev2.install) (the non`-dev` package) installs    `usr/lib/*/libshadowsocks-libev.so.*` (i.e. the actual binary).

[The README.md](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev#build-deb-package-from-source) contains rather detailed instructions for building from source on Debian-based platforms.

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation. About the Debian files in your list, I still don't understand where the files come from, maybe like cp xx usr/include/ , does the xx file in a specific path?

Comment: That looks like English, but some words are probably missing, so I'm really not sure what you are trying to ask.  When you build a package, `debian/rules` creates the files in the current directory, so `usr/include` really means the `include` directory in the `usr` directory in the current directory. But typically those files would then end up in `/usr/include` when `dpkg` installs the package.

Comment: Apologize for my poor English~ I've got the answer, Mainly due to not familiar with CMake and deb package things, BTW, Thank you so much again  :)